# Applying for a PhD - Can't Decide on the Topic

Tags: phd, research-process, research-topic

I'm applying to a PhD programme in the UK, but feeling kind of lost. I have two ideas for potential research topics (in the humanities - literature to be specific) but don't know which to go with?

I think the first topic is more novel than the second, but will require more effort, and I am not sure of:

whether i'll easily find the resources I need as I hope to apply the chosen theory to literature in my language and i'm not sure of what I'll find.

I also intend on doing some fieldwork, but don't know if the scholarship will cover me flying to my country to do the fieldwork and back.
Quite simply, I think the first topic will have more obstacles, even though I also wonder if these challenges will help me grow or just unnecessarily stress me out.

I also have a history of tending to work hard not smart and, therefore, have mostly leaned towards and chosen the harder path towards obtaining my degrees and even in my work. I.e. one example is that my friends all chose topics which were attainable in the specified time frame whilst doing their masters. I chose a topic which required a lot of research in a very short time frame in different fields I had not studied before which added to the stress as I had a lot to teach myself in a very short time. I did that but I was also happy that I produced work which was original (even though that is not usually the requirement for a master's degree) and learnt a lot, but I also wondered whether I should have just gone with an easier route.

Back to my question on topics - the second topic kind of builds on my master's topic and won't require fieldwork as it is more theoretical based, but I am not sure if I'll be enthusiastic about it as much as the first. I'm sure i'll be able to find something novel about it and add new knowledge, but not sure if the topic is worth spending three years researching it.
Also, the first topic I can see a future for especially in my field, but maybe in other places other than the UK.

I hope my post isn't confusing, but I really don't know how to pick one. Any insights or advice would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Have you been accepted into a doctoral program or just considering how to present yourself? Also, is the application to a specific advisor/supervisor or to a "system" of department that uses a committee structure?

Comment: @Buffy in the UK one applies with a research proposal. One cannot be accepted without one and I believe the poster is asking about that proposal. There also will not be an application to a specific supervisor but also not quite the system/committee you mention. They will likely be applying for a particular funding stream (internal, the AHRC, something else) and will need to designate a supervisor for that. If it is external/research council funding (again like AHRC) the university will select finalist to go forward for it outside the Uni based on the quality of the proposal.

Comment: This seems like a question that needs specific advice from people who know the field. It could be a reasonable thing to discuss with prospective supervisors, and/or you could talk to people from your former institution(s) e.g. your Masters supervisor and whoever else you intend to use as referees. On the whole people are happy to offer advice, so don't be afraid to reach out.

Comment: Also: pick the topic that you find most exciting. You're going to spend 3+ years of your life on this, and there are going to be low points. You need to care about the question, and not just about the end result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The biggest insight I can offer you here, because you are applying in the UK, is that you need to select the most mature and appealing of the ideas if you wish to be awarded funding for it. You need to select the most *fundable* topic: so the most feasible, interesting, and structurally sound. If you prefer the one that is less fundable, now is not the time to apply, you need to work on that idea more. Competition for funding is fierce and you need to present your best.

If, for example, you are applying for an AHRC studentship, your proposal will need to go through the University's internal selection round before it goes out to the AHRC for consideration, thus you have to write to appeal both to the university and to the AHRC beyond. This is something that you should be doing in partial collaboration with your prospective supervisors, although they will expect you to have a mature topic to shape.

Good luck, but also consider having a meeting with your prospective supervisor so they can go through how it all works. They can also help you consider the two ideas within the political context of the university and the funding body, and give you an assessment of your chances with each.